# Cast property values back to original types for comparison with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm currently trying to compare to data contracts using reflection.

The data contract represents a configuration for a virtual machine. They are both the same class type. I'm trying to log every change in the configuration when setting a new config. However, the data contracts have a large number of members. It'd be rather tedious to do it manually and it does not accommodate new data members being added later.

I tried using reflection to do it. I've managed to get the values of the data members, but depending on the actual type, comparing them will vary.

Some of the members being compared are :

- `IEnumerable<Subnets>`
- `IEnumerable<IP Address>`
- `X509Certificates`
- `Enums`

and a few more

I'm trying to find a way to cast the property to it's actual class, but everything I've found thus far has failed to work.

Here is an example of what I've done so far with reflection.

```
ExampleClass firstExample = new ExampleClass("a", 1);
ExampleClass secondExample = new ExampleClass("a", 2);
List<string> exampleList = new List<string>()
{
    "a",
    "b"
};

firstExample.ValueThree = exampleList;
secondExample.ValueThree = exampleList;

firstExample.FourthValue = new List<string>()
{
    "c",
    "d"
};

secondExample.FourthValue = new List<string>()
{
    "c",
    "d"
};

Type exampleType = firstExample.GetType();

foreach (PropertyInfo item in exampleType.GetProperties())
{
    var firstExampleValue = item.GetValue(firstExample);
    var secondExampleValue = item.GetValue(secondExample);
    string propName = item.Name;

    bool areEqual = firstExampleValue.Equals(secondExampleValue);

    Console.WriteLine(propName);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\nFirst Value : {0}\nSecond Value : {1}", firstExampleValue, secondExampleValue));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Values are equal : {0}\n\n", areEqual));
}
```

Is there a practical way to convert these to there actual classes as defined by the data contract? I've looked into `Convert.ChangeType` but found that this will not work for a good portion of the members as they are not `IConvertable`.

Thanks,

Edwin

Answer (score 0):

This isn't about getting the underlying type. This is about what is considered "equal".

In .NET, every type inherits from `object` and thus inherits [`Object.Equals()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals). But for reference types `Object.Equals()` will only compare whether the two objects are the *exact same object*, not whether their contents are equal.

For example, `new List<string>() == new List<string>()` will always be `false`.

That's why `firstExample == secondExample` and `firstExampleValue.Equals(secondExampleValue)` will always be `false`.

However, classes can override the `Equals` method. For example, `String` overrides `Equals()` so that it compares the contents of both.

In this case, if `ExampleClass` is a class that you control, you can override `Equals` and tell it to compare the contents of each property (and the contents of each `List`) to decide if they're equal. Once you do that, then you can just write `firstExample == secondExample` and it would be `true`.

The documentation of `Object.Equals()` actually has a simple example of that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals

*Update:* Casting to the underlying type doesn't give you any advantage. Even if a type is cast to `object`, it still uses `Equals` from the underlying type when you compare. For example, this results in `true`: `((object)"hello") == ((object)"hello")` because it uses `String.Equals` not `Object.Equals`.

So your real problem is knowing whether the type has overridden `Equals`. You can test if a type has overridden `Equals` like this:

```
var type = typeof(string);
var overriddenEquals = type.GetMember("Equals").First().DeclaringType != typeof(object);
```

But that still doesn't help you for types that haven't overridden equals. How do you compare them?

The only way to do this is to be aware of the types that will be used and test for those specifically (a bunch of `if` statements) and decide how you will compare them. (for lists, you can test for `is IEnumerable`, loop through it, then test the type inside the list)

And in those cases, it doesn't matter if the type implements `IConvertible` since you will know what the type is and can cast directly to it, like:

```
if (obj is Subnets objSubnets) {
    //compare objSubnets to another Subnets object
}
```

Comment: I’m aware of that. Hence why I want to have my own custom way of comparing each datamember by there actual type. The data members will be different instances but have similar values. A data member that is a string or int is easy to compare, but some other more complex members not so much

Comment: Unfortunately that still won't help. I updated my answer to explain why.